# Can I change Android style's parent in code?

Tags: android, themes, styles

At the moment my base style inherits from `android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`. Is there any way I can change it to inherit from `Theme.Black.NoTitleBar` in code? I notice apps like Handcent has a settings option to do this, but I can't quite figure out how to do this.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
D.

Comment: Do you want to hide the title bar?

Comment: Yes, I would like to keep the title bar hidden. Basically I want to be able to switch between Light and Black themes in runtime

Answer (score 2):

You can do this -

> @Override
>
> public void onCreate(Bundle
>   savedInstanceState){
>
> super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
> setTheme(android.R.style.Theme.Black.NoTitleBar);
>
> setContentView(R.layout.main);
>
> }}

}

Comment: I have the app's style set in the manifest xml and have already tried the above code. It did not change the style at all actually.